# String object versus literal - modifying the prototype?

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering why it seems that adding a method to the prototype of a string literal seems to work, but adding a property does not? I was playing with ideas in relation to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3756335/i-am-trying-to-create-a-substr-method-with-a-pointer-is-there-a-more-elegant), and have the following code:

```
String.prototype._str_index1 = 0;
String.prototype._str_reset = function() {
    this._str_index1 = 0;
};
String.prototype._str_substr = function(len) {
  var ret = this.substr(this._str_index1, len);
  this._str_index1 = this._str_index1 + len;
  return ret;
};

var testString = new String('Loremipsumdolorsitamet,consectetur');
log(testString._str_substr(5));
log(testString._str_substr(4));
​
```

This works fine. If however I change the third-last line to:

```
var testString = 'Loremipsumdolorsitamet,consectetur';
```

...it seems that although the method `_str_substr` exists and is callable on the string literal, the value of the property `_str_index1` is always 0.

What's up?

Comment: *Most* of the things you call ‘string literal’, are actually called ‘string primitive’: literals are a syntax to describe a string, e.g., to assign a string (or number, boolean, object, etc.) to a variable; primitive values are non-composite values that variables and objects can contain (apart from (other) objects).

Comment: Except when it's not....'indexOf' is not a function when called against a string....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The string primitive is converted to a transient `String` object every time you try to invoke a method of the `String` object (the JavaScript engine internally converts a string primitive to a `String` object when necessary). After this function returns, the `String` object is (unobtrusively) converted back to a string primitive (under the hood) and this new primitive is returned (and most of the time assigned to a variable); **every time a method of the `String` object is invoked**.

So, after each invocation of `testString._str_substr`, `_str_index1` is thrown away with the object and a new object (with a reset `_str_index1`) is created when `_str_substr` is called again.

See also [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Description):

> Because JavaScript automatically converts between string primitives and String objects, you can call any of the methods of the String object on a string primitive. JavaScript automatically converts the string primitive to a temporary String object, calls the method, then discards the temporary String object.

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much what I was trying to say :)

Answer (score 2):

This happens because the object is created and immediately thrown away when the assignment is made, because it's a string literal.

So with the first version, an object is created and kept, so testString is an object, not a string literal. In the second case, an object is created and thrown away, so all properties get lost...

Now try replacing that line with this:

```
var testString = 'Loremipsumdolorsitamet,consectetur'._str_substr();
```

Interesting, right? It still returns a string primitive, but that could be fixed...

```
String.prototype._str_substr = function(len) {
  var ret = this.substr(this._str_index1, len);
  this._str_index1 = this._str_index1 + len;
  return new String(ret);
};
```

Of course these are just suggestions designed to help explain why literals act differently than objects, not real-world recommendations...

Comment: No me neither. @no, I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: “the object is created and immediately thrown away when the assignment is made” sounds like an object is created and thrown away on the *initial* assignment (`var testString = …`), not when invoking `_str_substr`.

Comment: Hmm, I'm looking for it in the ECMAScript specification, but can't find it (at least not at this hour). But if that would be the case, the method of the `String` object can't be called after the string assignment is made. The string primitive has to be converted every time a method of the `String` object is invoked.

Comment: Marcel: I think we're talking about the same thing... AFAIK a String object is temporarily created when a string is encountered and then thrown away. Maybe I'm wrong about that, the point was that it isn't an object from the time its declared, it's a primitive; stateless except for its value. When you call 'methods' of a string primitive it's just like applying String.prototype.x to the literal string.

Comment: You're correct (about that we're talking about the same thing).