# How is a Javascript string not an object?

Tags: javascript

*It's not the setup to a joke, i'm really asking.*

[Douglas Crockford is fond of saying](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2006/11/13/javascript-we-hardly-new-ya/) that in the javascript prototypal object-oriented language there is no need for `new`.

He explains that `new` was simply added to give people coming from class-based (i.e. "*classical*") object oriented programming languages some level of comfort:

> ## [JavaScript, We Hardly `new` Ya](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2006/11/13/javascript-we-hardly-new-ya/)
>
> JavaScript is a prototypal language, but it has a `new` operator that tries to make it look sort of like a classical language. That tends to confuse programmers, leading to some problematic programming patterns.
>
> You never need to use `new Object()` in JavaScript. Use the object literal `{}` instead.

Okay, fine:

- `new` bad
- `{}` good

But then commenter [Vítor De Araújo pointed out that the two are not the same](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2006/11/13/javascript-we-hardly-new-ya/#comment-588504). He gives an example showing that a `string` is not like an `object`:

> A string object and a string value are not the same thing:
>
> ```
> js> p = "Foo"
> Foo
> js> p.weight = 42
> 42
> js> p.weight // Returns undefined
>
> js> q = new String("Foo")
> Foo
> js> q.weight = 42
> 42
> js> q.weight
> 42
> ```
>
> The string value cannot have new properties. The same thing is valid for other types.

What is going on here that an `string` is not an `object`? Am i confusing javascript with some other languages, where everything is an object?

Comment: …and I do not totally agree with Crockford: it's not necessary to use `new Object` (neither is `new Array`, use `[]` instead), but if you want to define a new instance of a (pre)defined class, you really should use the `new` operator, like in `new Date()` or `new SchrodingersCat()`.

Comment: @Marcel Korpel: *"should use"*, or **must** *use*? Is there any other way to construct a new object from the `Date` object prototype?

Comment: Good question, in case of `Date`: **must**. If you call `Date` as a bare function, it returns the current date and time as a string. Also see [Using constructor without operator 'new'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928342/using-constructor-without-operator-new) and [Does Javascript's new operator do anything but make life difficult?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744426/does-javascripts-new-operator-do-anything-but-make-life-difficult)

Comment: @Marcel Korpel: Those links make things more confusing. What does `new Date` do? What does `new` do? Does javascript have constructors? How does one declare a constructor in javascript? How does one call a constructor in javascript? Does `new` call a constructor?

Comment: In short (just moved and don't have an internet connection at home): `new` creates a new object and calls the constructor function. `new Date` creates a new `Date` object set to the given time (instead of returning the current date/time as a string). For a better explanation I recommend you to read David Flanagan's *JavaScript: The Definitive Guide*.

Comment: Class? what class?  That is the whole point of a prototype OO system, is that there are no classes to use.

Comment: See also [Why are there two kinds of JavaScript strings?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5514367/1048572)

Answer (score 103, accepted):

*"Everything is an object"*... that's one of the big misconceptions that exist all around the language.

**Not** *everything* is an object, there are what we call *primitive values*, which are string, number, boolean, null, and undefined.

That's true, a string is a **primitive value**, but you can access all the methods inherited from `String.prototype` as if it were an object.

The property [accessor operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) (the dot and the bracket notation), temporarily convert the string value to a String object, for being able to access those methods, e.g.:

```
"ab".charAt(1); // "b"
```

What happens behind the scenes is something like this:

```
new String("ab").charAt(1); // "b", temporal conversion ToObject
```

As with the other primitive values, such as `Boolean`, and `Number`, there are *object wrappers*, which are simply objects that contain the primitive value, as in your example:

```
var strObj = new String("");
strObj.prop = "foo";

typeof strObj; // "object"
typeof strObj.prop; // "string"
```

While with a primitive:

```
var strValue = "";
strValue.prop = "foo";

typeof strValue; // "string"
typeof strValue.prop; // "undefined"
```

And this happens because again, the property accessor on the second line above, creates a new temporal object, as:

```
var strValue = "";
new String(strValue).prop = "foo"; // a new object which is discarded
//...
```

Comment: I prefer to not use uppercase with primitives, like `boolean` and `number`, to avoid confusion with the object wrappers `Boolean` and `Number` (but the ECMAScript specification does not do so). Also, `NaN` is a primitive value, too.

Comment: Marcel, yeah, object wrappers can cause confusion, e.g. `if (new Boolean(false)) {alert(':D');}`. Yes, `NaN`, positive and negative `Infinity` are values of the [Number type](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_8.5).

Comment: Ah, yes, `Infinity`, I already thought I forgot some other value. How can one ever forget `Infinity`?

Comment: I want to stress that when using object methods to primitive values, the variable is only *temporarily* converted to an object and after the proposed operation, the object is converted back to a primitive. This concept can cause confusion, as you can see in [String object versus literal - modifying the prototype?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3756549/258127)

Comment: Even after two years this answer remains effective! +1!!

Comment: Yes!  Thank you CMS.  +1 for great answer AND being the first time I have ever seen the ECMA specs linked!  (bookmarked!)

Comment: @CMS is this still valid ? or do the primitives themselves start as fully fledged objects in the latest JS implementations. It seems expensive to convert the primitives behind the scenes every time you invoke a method on them to an Object, and for almost every other operation. This is especially true in Python, where **everything** starts as an object, not converted on the fly or at a later time, so for instance the number `3` is an instance of `int` (talking about Python now), where that instance holds both the value and the methods.

Comment: @MariusMucenicu, this holds true, but in a practical sense, I'm pretty sure the JS engines have optimized and inlined the access of prototype members on primitive values.

Answer (score 4):

The most important difference between a string and an object is that objects must follow [this rule for the `==` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators):

> An expression comparing Objects is only true if the operands reference
>   the same Object.

So, whereas strings have a convenient `==` that compares the value, you're out of luck when it comes to making any other immutable object type behave like a value type.
(There may be other differences too, but this is the only one that causes JavaScript developers excitement on a daily basis). Examples:

```
"hello" == "hello"
-> true
new String("hello") == new String("hello") // beware!
-> false
```

Comment: this is the wrong comparison, these are clearly 2 different objects, so to compare the strings, you need to compare the values of `new String("hello").valueOf()`

Comment: @MichaelHabib It is the right comparison to demonstrate that comparing two objects compares the reference. Of course, you can convert the `String` object back to a `string` and compare it as a value. But the question is about how objects behave differently from strings. (Not about how to compare the values of objects).