# How to get an object's properties in JavaScript / jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In JavaScript / jQuery, if I `alert` some object, I get either `[object]` or  `[object Object]`

Is there any way to know:

1. what is the difference between these two objects
2. what type of Object is this
3. what all properties does this object contains and values of each property

?

Comment: HOw can i print a javascript Object ! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/957537/how-can-i-print-a-javascript-object

Comment: I found a helpful documentation too http://docs.jquery.com/Types

Answer (score 153, accepted):

You can look up an object's keys and values by either invoking JavaScript's native `for in` loop:

```
var obj = {
    foo:    'bar',
    base:   'ball'
};

for(var key in obj) {
    alert('key: ' + key + '\n' + 'value: ' + obj[key]);
}
```

or using jQuery's `.each()` method:

```
$.each(obj, function(key, element) {
    alert('key: ' + key + '\n' + 'value: ' + element);
});
```

[With the exception of six primitive types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive), **everything** in ECMA-/JavaScript is an object. Arrays; functions; everything is an object. Even most of those primitives are actually also objects with a limited selection of methods. They are cast into objects under the hood, when required. To know the base class name, you may invoke the `Object.prototype.toString` method on an object, like this:

```
alert(Object.prototype.toString.call([]));
```

The above will output `[object Array]`.

There are several other class names, like `[object Object]`, `[object Function]`, `[object Date]`, `[object String]`, `[object Number]`, `[object Array]`, and `[object Regex]`.

Comment: "Everything is an object", that's not true, and it is one of the big misconceptions in the language. There are what we call primitive types: Number, String, Boolean, Undefined and Null. They can be often confused with the primitive wrappers, objects created with built-in constructors, e.g.: `typeof new String("foo");` produces "object", it is a wrapped primitive value, while `typeof "foo";` produces "string". [See also](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907613/how-is-a-javascript-string-not-an-object/)

Comment: I agree with CMS and once you run into the difference between a primitive string and the String object, you'll realize your capabilities ~ especially when trying to minimize code.

Comment: @CMS That's not quite true, either.  The "primitive" string _is_ an object in its own right; it just has a different selection of methods.  Likewise with numbers and booleans.  However, Undefined and Null are primitives without methods.

Comment: @Izkata not true.  `var str = 'primitive'; str.foo = 'bar'; /*wouldn't work*/` whereas `var oStr = new String('string object');  oStr.foo = 'bar'; /*works*/`  If you're going to abstract it and call them all objects, then you can get away with thinking of primitives as primitive objects, but it's not equivalent to the superclass of true JavaScript objects.

Comment: simply use `console.log` to inspect objects

Answer (score 13):

#### To get listing of object properties/values:

1. In Firefox - Firebug:

   ```
   console.dir(<object>);
   ```
2. Standard JS to get object keys borrowed from [Slashnick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208016/how-to-list-the-properties-of-a-javascript-object):

   ```
      var fGetKeys = function(obj){
         var keys = [];
         for(var key in obj){
            keys.push(key);
         }
         return keys;
      }

   // Example to call it:

      var arrKeys = fGetKeys(document);

      for (var i=0, n=arrKeys.length; i<n; i++){
         console.log(i+1 + " - " + arrKeys[i] + document[arrKeys[i]] + "\n");
      }
   ```

---

#### Edits:

1. `<object>` in the above is to be replaced with the variable reference to the object.
2. `console.log()` is to be used in the console, if you're unsure what that is, you can replace it with an `alert()`

Answer (score 7):

> **i) what is the difference between these two objects**

The simple answer is that `[object]` indicates a host object that has no internal class.  A host object is an object that is not part of the ECMAScript implementation you're working with, but is provided by the host as an extension.  The DOM is a common example of host objects, although in most newer implementations DOM objects inherit from the native Object and have internal class names (such as *HTMLElement*, *Window*, etc).  IE's proprietary ActiveXObject is another example of a host object.

`[object]` is most commonly seen when alerting DOM objects in Internet Explorer 7 and lower, since they are host objects that have no internal class name.

> **ii) what type of Object is this**

You can get the "type" (internal class) of object using `Object.prototype.toString`.  The specification requires that it always returns a string in the format `[object [[Class]]]`, where `[[Class]]` is the internal class name such as *Object*, *Array*, *Date*, *RegExp*, etc.  You can apply this method to any object (including host objects), using

```
Object.prototype.toString.apply(obj);
```

Many `isArray` implementations use this technique to discover whether an object is actually an array (although [it's not as robust in IE as it is in other browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058427/how-to-detect-if-a-variable-is-an-array/4029057#4029057)).

> **iii) what all properties does this object contains and values of each property**

In ECMAScript 3, you can iterate over enumerable properties using a `for...in` loop.  Note that most built-in properties are non-enumerable.  The same is true of some host objects.  In ECMAScript 5, you can get an array containing the names of all non-inherited properties using `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj)`.  This array will contain non-enumerable and enumerable property names.

Answer (score 4):

I hope this doesn't count as spam. I humbly ended up writing a function after endless debug sessions: http://github.com/halilim/Javascript-Simple-Object-Inspect

```
function simpleObjInspect(oObj, key, tabLvl)
{
    key = key || "";
    tabLvl = tabLvl || 1;
    var tabs = "";
    for(var i = 1; i < tabLvl; i++){
        tabs += "\t";
    }
    var keyTypeStr = " (" + typeof key + ")";
    if (tabLvl == 1) {
        keyTypeStr = "(self)";
    }
    var s = tabs + key + keyTypeStr + " : ";
    if (typeof oObj == "object" && oObj !== null) {
        s += typeof oObj + "\n";
        for (var k in oObj) {
            if (oObj.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
                s += simpleObjInspect(oObj[k], k, tabLvl + 1);
            }
        }
    } else {
        s += "" + oObj + " (" + typeof oObj + ") \n";
    }
    return s;
}
```

**Usage**

```
alert(simpleObjInspect(anyObject));
```

or

```
console.log(simpleObjInspect(anyObject));
```

Answer (score 2):

Get [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) for Mozilla Firefox.

use `console.log(obj);`

Comment: I fail to see how your firebug is any different from mine, but I'd use dir instead of log to list the object

Comment: `console.log` is just as effective, you can click on the object in the log to get the "dir" anyway...

Answer (score 1):

[Spotlight.js](https://github.com/bestiejs/spotlight.js/) is a great library for iterating over the window object and other host objects looking for certain things.

```
// find all "length" properties
spotlight.byName('length');

// or find all "map" properties on jQuery
spotlight.byName('map', { 'object': jQuery, 'path': '$' });

// or all properties with `RegExp` values
spotlight.byKind('RegExp');

// or all properties containing "oo" in their name
spotlight.custom(function(value, key) { return key.indexOf('oo') > -1; });
```

You'll like it for this.

Answer (score 0):

Scanning object for first intance of a determinated prop:

```
var obj = {a:'Saludos',
            b:{b_1:{b_1_1:'Como estas?',b_1_2:'Un gusto conocerte'}},
           d:'Hasta luego'
            }
function scan (element,list){
    var res;
    if (typeof(list) != 'undefined'){
        if (typeof(list) == 'object'){
            for(key in list){
               if (typeof(res) == 'undefined'){
                res = (key == element)?list[key]:scan(element,list[key]);
               }
            });
        }
    }
    return res;
}
console.log(scan('a',obj));
```