# Dynamically Reading Array Values form a JSON Object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am working on a function that accepts a JSON object as a parameter. Each property of the object passed in will be an array. I need to determine the length of each of these arrays.

What I won't know in advance are: the names of the properties, or how many properties there are.

How can I determine the length of each array? Again, I can't refer to any of the properties/keys explicitly because I won't know their names ahead of time. How do I reference each unknown property as an array?

Thank you in advance,
-RS

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get an object's properties in JavaScript / jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079274/how-to-get-an-objects-properties-in-javascript-jquery)

Comment: You can get the length of an array from its `length` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over the object using a `for...in` loop to access each property.

```
for (var key in myObject) {
  // Check to make sure the property is not part of the `Object` prototype (eg. toString)
  if (myObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    console.log(key, myObject[key].length);
  }
}
```

In the above example, we iterate over the properties of the object `myObject` and we log out their length values (assuming they are all arrays).

If by "JSON object" you mean that it is a string of JSON, you can first parse myObject into a true object by using `myObject = JSON.parse(myObject)` (which works in modern browsers) or `myObject = eval("(" + myOjbect + ")")` which is considered unsafe (but works in all browsers). After parsing, you may use the above technique to fine array lengths.

Note: Since you updated the post to specify that the object is JSON, you may not *need* the `hasOwnProperty` check, but it is safer to always use this test.

Comment: Action Jake: Thank you. This is the approach I was using, but now I see what I was missing. I'll use your variable names to illustrate: I was trying to reference the arrays in the for...in loop using myObject instead of myObject[key]. Therefore, myObject.length simply returned the length of the String containing the key's name. Thank you!

Comment: Ah... yes, you were assuming the functionality of the new `for...of` loop in ES6 :) https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of Unfortunately, you'll have to wait a while yet to use this.

Comment: Correction":  I was trying to reference the arrays in the for...in loop using key instead of myObject[key]. Therefore, key.length simply returned the length of the String containing the key's name.

Answer (score 0):

Use `JSON.parse` to convert JSON data to JS Objects, and then you can use Array's length etc properties.

```
var myObject = JSON.parse(myJSONtext, reviver);
```

JSON Reference: http://www.json.org/js.html

Comment: Thanks, but I wasn't asking how to parse.