# Looping through JavaScript objects and logging their attributes?

Tags: javascript, object

I want to loop through an array of objects, and for each object console.log its attributes. Let's say we don't know what the attributes are.

The code looks like this.

```
qData = [object ,object, object, object, object];
for(props in qData){
  //display all of props object attributes
}
```

How can I output their attributes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get an object's properties in JavaScript / jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079274/how-to-get-an-objects-properties-in-javascript-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that like this:

```
var qData = [object, object, object, object, object];
for (var i = 0; i < qData.length; i++) {
    var obj = qData[i];
    for (var prop in obj) {
        console.log(prop + "=" + obj[prop]);
    }
}
```

You first iterate through the array and then for each array element, you iterate through the properties.  Keep in mind that you iterate array elements with `for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)` and you iterate properties with `for (props in array)`.

---

If you only want direct properties of the object (and not any enumerable properties of parent objects), you would use this:

```
var qData = [object, object, object, object, object];
for (var i = 0; i < qData.length; i++) {
    var obj = qData[i];
    for (var prop in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            console.log(prop + "=" + obj[prop]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your `props` variable is an implicit global.