# dynamically change array property value in jquery

Tags: jquery

My array contains NewColumn_1, NewColumn_2, NewColumn_3 etc... I am getting Max NewColumn_ Value in Array. Here NewColumn_SomeValue generating dynamically.

```
var products = [{
    "ProductID": 1,
    "ProductName": "Chai",
    NewColumn_1:'abc'
    NewColumn_2:'abc',
    NewColumn_3:'abc',
    NewColumn_4:'abc'
},{
    "ProductID": 2,
    "ProductName": "Chang",
    NewColumn_1:'def',
    NewColumn_2:'abc',
    NewColumn_3:'abc',
    NewColumn_4:'abc'
}]

var fieldValue = "NewColumn_" + (maxValueInArray);

products[i].NewColumn = jsonData[i].Title;
```

I need to `products[i].fieldValue =jsonData[i].Title;` 
i am unable to do. can any one help this.

Comment: there is no `products[i].NewColumn`, it should be column 1,2,3.... like `products[i].NewColumn_1`

Comment: yes instead that i need max one. means fieldValue

Comment: What does mean `max` in this context? Max value from all object fields (it will be quite strange to compare strings)? Or max index of `NewColumn_X` (which is always `NewColumn_4`)?

Comment: No. Here i am generating Newcloums. we can say NewColumn_4 is max one. it can be NewColumn_5, NewColumn_6,NewColumn_7 etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code below

```
var lengths = [], length;

for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
    length = 0;
    for (var property in products[i]) {
        if (property.indexOf("NewColumn_") == 0) {
            length++;
        }
    }
    lengths.push(length);
}

var maximum = Math.max.apply(null, lengths);
```

Reference:
[How to get an object's properties in JavaScript / jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079274/how-to-get-an-objects-properties-in-javascript-jquery) and
[JavaScript: min & max Array values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669190/javascript-min-max-array-values)

Comment: i am getting max value. just i need to give like  products[i].fieldValue =jsonData[i].Title; i am unable to do that.

Comment: `products[i]['NewColumn_' + maximum] = data`

Comment: @Ram, please mark the answer as correct and close the post, thanks.