# Why are there two kinds of JavaScript strings?

Tags: javascript, string

This one just stabbed me hard. I don't know if it's the case with all browsers (I don't have any other competent browser to test with), but at least Firefox has two kind of string objects.

Open up the Firebugs console and try the following:

```
>>> "a"
"a"
>>> new String("a")
String { 0="a"}
```

As you can visually observe, Firefox treats `new String("a")` and `"a"` differently. Otherwise however, both kinds of strings seem to behave the same. There is, for instance, evidence that both use the same prototype object:

```
>>> String.prototype.log = function() { console.log("Logged string: " + this); }
function()
>>> "hello world".log()
Logged string: hello world
>>> new String("hello world").log()
Logged string: hello world
```

So apparently, both are the same. That is, until you ask for the type.

```
>>> typeof("a")
"string"
>>> typeof(new String("a"))
"object"
```

We can also notice that when `this` is a string, it's always the object form:

```
>>> var identity = function() { return this }
>>> identity.call("a")
String { 0="a"}
>>> identity.call(new String("a"))
String { 0="a"}
```

Going a bit further, we can see that the non-object string representation doesn't support any additional properties, but the object string does:

```
>>> var a = "a"
>>> var b = new String("b")
>>> a.bar = 4
4
>>> b.bar = 4
4
>>> a.bar
undefined
>>> b.bar
4
```

Also, fun fact! You can turn a string object into a non-object string by using the `toString()` function:

```
>>> new String("foo").toString()
"foo"
```

Never thought it could be useful to call `String.toString()`! Anyways.

So all these experiments beg the question: why are there two kinds of strings in JavaScript?

---

Comments show this is also the case for every primitive JavaScript type (numbers and bools included).

Comment: There are two kinds of numbers, too ...

Comment: And two types of booleans `true === new Boolean(true); // false`

Comment: Let's just say JavaScript is a binarily-typed language...

Comment: In other words, every primitive has a wrapped type (which I find completely useless)

Comment: See also [How is a Javascript string not an object?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3907613/1048572)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are two types of strings in Javascript -- literal strings and String objects.  They do behave a little differently. The main difference between the two is that you can add additional methods and properties to a String object. For instance:

```
var strObj = new String("object mode");
strObj.string_mode = "object"
strObj.get_string_mode = function() { return this.string_mode; }

// this converts it from an Object to a primitive string:
str = strObj.toString();
```

A string literal is just temporarily cast to a String object to perform any of the core methods.

The same kinds of concepts apply to other data types, too. [Here's more on primitive data types and objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_syntax#Primitive_data_types).

**EDIT**

As noted in the comments, string literals are not primitive strings, rather a "literal constant whose type is a built-in primitive [string] value", citing [this source](http://www.ssicom.org/js/x17038.htm).

Comment: It's string *primitives* rather than literals. See my comment to Raynos's answer.

Comment: The terms _literal_ and _primitive_ seem to be used loosely, whether or not that is by-the-book. Wikipedia uses both terms in the same thought: "JavaScript provides a Boolean data type with true and false literals. The typeof operator returns the string 'boolean' for these primitives."

Comment: @Kelly: They're different things though. In the case of string, a literal produces a primitive string, but string primitives are also produced by calling `toString()` on any native JavaScript object.

Comment: @TimDown it's string _values_ rather then primitives. See ES5 specification.

Comment: @Raynos: *primitive* is very much an acceptable term, and is applied to the collective of string, number and boolean values throughout the ECMAScript 5 specification.  There's also the `ToPrimitive` internal method and `[[PrimitiveValue]]` attribute, the former returns a primitive value which could be any of the primitive types. So either string value or string primitive should be an acceptable term.

Comment: @AndyE that's the primitive value of an object. That's subtly different. But it is a acceptable term.

Comment: @Raynos: You're right, even the third edition of the spec does refer to them as string values.

Answer (score 2):

Your comparing string values to string objects.

`"a"` is a string value.

`"a" === "a"; // true`

`new String("a")` is an string object.

`new String("a") === new String("a"); // false`

There both strings. `"a"` just gets the string value "a" where as `new String("a")` creates a new string object which internally has the string value "a"

Comment: Does that mean `new String("foo" + "bar").toString()` creates a global, static `"foobar"` string?

Comment: Create might be the wrong word. It returns a string literal though.

Comment: How does it bring "foobar" into existence if "creating" is not the right verb? Also, do you think those "global static" strings ever get garbage-collected/recycled?

Comment: @zneak global static is the wrong word to use. I'm not sure where the literals live internally in the javascript engine. I presume they live in a symbol table somewhere. But calling `toString()` returns a literal which is made and assigned a place in RAM somewhere and if you ever call it again you get the same object back.

Comment: Slightly inaccurate: the difference is between string primitives and String objects. String literals do produce string primitives but are not the only way to do so. `toString()` on any JavaScript object produces a string primitive too.

Comment: Agreed, I would fix up the terminology.  A "literal" defines the grammar necessary to create something without using a constructor function.  A literal can create a primitive or an object (see object/array literals) and as @Tim Down said, primitives can be created from objects.

Comment: @TimDown @AndyE changed the wording to match ES5 specification.

Answer (score 0):

Another important thing to remember is the following:

```
typeof "my-string" // "string"
typeof String('my-string') // 'string'
typeof new String("my-string") // "object".
```

Therefore, when testing  whether an argument or variable is a string you need to do at least the following.

```
function isString(arg) {
  if (!arg) {
    return false;
  }
  return typeof arg == "string" || arg.constructor == String;
}
```

The above function will still fail if you pass in a String object from another frame/iframe. That is:

```
frames[0].myStringVar.constructor != frames[1].myStringVar.constructor
```

That is because the constructor `String` is different for each window context. Therefore, a foolproof isString method would be

```
function isString(obj) {
   return Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) == "[object String]";
}
```

Comment: Isn't your latest `isString` function rather a `toString` function?