# what would be the reason that any framework, or anyone, would ever need to use String/Number/Boolean object as opposed to the primitive versions?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are there two kinds of JavaScript strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5514367/why-are-there-two-kinds-of-javascript-strings)

For example, we need to use `new RegExp()` instead of the regex literal if we need the regex expression to be dynamically calculated.

However exactly what are the *edge cases* when anyone will ever need to use String/Number/Boolean objects as opposed to their primitive versions ? (because I can't seem to even think of one where it will ever  be needed)

Comment: I voted it up anyway because it is a good question.

Comment: One reason I could think of would be to add a new property to particular string instance (for whatever reason). You'd have to create this string with `new String`.

Answer (score 1):

A `String` is an `Object`, but the primitive version exists which is created as a literal with `'Hello'` (and is by far the most common used).

People sometimes use `new String()` to convert another type to a `String`, for example, in a function.

```
function leadingZero(number, padding) {
   number = new String(number);
   ...
}
```

Leading 0s are not significant in a `Number`, so it must be a `String`.

However, I still would have preferred to have made the `Number` a `String` by concatenating it with an empty `String` (`''`).

```
function leadingZero(number, padding) {
   number += '';
   ...
}
```

This will implicitly call the `toString()` of the `Number`, returning a `String` primitive.

> I was reading that people say *hey `typeof foo==="string"` is not fool-proof because if the string is created using `new String` the `typeof` will give us `object`*.

You can make a fool proof `isString()` method like so...

```
var isString = function(str) {
   return Object.prototype.toString.call(str) == '[object String]'; 
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/QYqF8/).

This works in a multi `window` environment. You could also check the `constructor` property, but this fails in a multi `window` environment.

Also refer to [Felix Kling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218196/felix-kling)'s comments to this answer.

Comment: You can also convert to a string by calling the `toString()` method directly.

Comment: yep that's what i'm saying. is there any benefit in using `new String` as compared to concatenation with "" ? otherwise why would people even have a reason to use `new String` *at all* ?

Comment: @Felix You are correct, I believe concatenating with a string will implicitly call that method (`toString()`) on non `String`s.

Comment: @Pacerier Not really. I've always stuck with the primitives. There are also `new Number()`, `new Boolean()`, `new Array()`, etc. The primitive or literal versions are always preferred except for edge cases.

Comment: @Pacerier: Using the constructor functions for these data types is discouraged because of exactly these troubles they could cause. There is really hardly a reason why you should use them. If you do see them used somewhere, it is likely that whoever wrote the code has not a good understanding of JavaScript.

Comment: @alex what are the edge cases? (actually that exactly is my question, but i didn't know how to phrase it until you have phrased it)

Comment: @Felix take a look at the edited question. if you say there are hardly any reasons why we would use them, you do mean that there will still be reasons that we will use them right? what exactly are those reasons?

Comment: @Pacerier For example, `new RegExp()` must be used if you need to the regex as a string (to possibly concatenate portions of another string). For the `String` object, I'm not sure what edge cases would exist for *anyone* to use the constructor over the primitive. One difference is the `String` constructor can have additional properties set on the Object whilst the primitive can't. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/MrFrL/).

Comment: @alex nice point about the RegExp. i've incorporated it into the question to make the question clearer

Comment: @Pacerier OK, your question seems to have a wider scope then it was originally so I have voted to reopen it. Do you want a list of edge cases per Object, or just to know that *yes, there are certain edge cases where the constructor is necessary, don't entirely dismiss the Object constructors*?

Comment: @alex yes a list of edge cases per Object would be cool, because simply *"yes, there are certain edge cases where the constructor is necessary"* without evidence is not convincing at all..