# Verify each line of a text area starts with something

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to validate a textarea making sure that each line starts with 'http://':

http://jsfiddle.net/n8zYB/1/

When the url is wrong, it executes the else statement but if it's correct, it isn't getting executed.

What's the problem?

Comment: Can you show the code you've written?   Kind of hard to answer without it...

Comment: @Sparky The jsfiddle is the code

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize what the link was.   Looks like you've already got some answers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because `this` refers to a String object. the `after` function expects a jQuery object or a string. Strangely enough, in javascript strings are different from String objects. Your else statement works because `this` is being converted into a string behind the scenes when you concat a regular string to it. However, the if fails because `this` remains a String object in this case. You can fix it in a couple of ways, but here is one of them:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    var links = $('textarea').val().split('\n');

    $.each(links,function(){
        if( this.substr(0, 7) == 'http://' )
            $('p').after(''+this);
        else
            $('p').after('error: '+this+'<br/>');
    });
    return false;
});
```

**EDIT**

here's a link to another SO question that discusses this in more detail [Why are there two kinds of JavaScript strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5514367/why-are-there-two-kinds-of-javascript-strings)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `$.each` to iterate an array. Use this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    if(links[i].substring(0, 7) !== 'http://' && links[i].substring(0, 8) !== 'https://') {
        $('p').text('Error!');
        return false;
    }
}
```

[Here's a demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/n8zYB/2/)

Comment: I'm curious - why not `$.each`? Why doesn't even `$.each(links,function(){$('p').after(this);});` work? -- nvm, just saw @Chris N's explanation.

Comment: @mathematical.coffee: Actually, his explanation is partially wrong. Brian Glaz explains it better.

Comment: @minitech @ your new edit, but that would require both right?

Comment: @user1099531: No, it wouldn't. I'm using `!==`; if a is not b and a is not c (either).

Answer (score 0):

It is not working because of `$('p').after(this);`. In this case, `this` is just a string literal.

The `after` function's first parameter should be an HTML string, DOM element, or jQuery object to insert after each element in the set of matched elements.

Here's an [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n8zYB/3/)

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    var links = $('textarea').val().split('\n');

    $.each(links,function(){
        if( this.substr(0, 7) == 'http://' )
            $('p:last').after("<p>" + this + "</p>");
        else
            $('p:last').after('error: '+this+'<br/>');
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be little better, try it

```
$('button').click(function(){
    var links = $('textarea').val().split('\n');

    $.each(links,function(){
        if( this.substr(0, 7) == 'http://' )
            $('#mydiv').append(this + '<br/>');
        else
            $('#mydiv').append('<span style="color:red;">error: '+this+'</span><br/>');
    });
    return false;
});
```

HTML:

```
<textarea></textarea>
<button>Submit</button>
<div id='mydiv'></div>
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/n8zYB/6/