# Can (a==1 && a==2 && a==3) evaluate to true in C# without multi-threading?

Tags: c#

[I know it could be done in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48270127/476716)

But is there any possible solution to print "Hurraa" on the condition given below in C# without multi-threading?

```
if (a==1 && a==2 && a==3) {
    Console.WriteLine("Hurraa");
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `a`? Is it a local variable, a field, or a property?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Sure, its the same concept as a few of the javascript answers.  You have a side effect in a property getter.

```
private static int _a;
public static int a { get { return ++_a; } set { _a = value; } }
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    a = 0;
    if (a == 1 && a == 2 && a == 3)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hurraa");
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Of course you do not really need the assignment `a = 0`, and you can leave out the `set` accessor inside `a` entirely. Just if you want a shorter code example.

Answer (score 22):

Sure, you can overload `operator ==` to do whatever you want.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace UnitTestProject1
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            var a = new AlwaysEqual();
            Assert.IsTrue(a == 1 && a == 2 && a == 3);
        }

        class AlwaysEqual
        {
            public static bool operator ==(AlwaysEqual c, int i) => true;
            public static bool operator !=(AlwaysEqual c, int i) => !(c == i);
            public override bool Equals(object o) => true;
            public override int GetHashCode() => true.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is so easy in C# compared to JavaScript.

Comment: @SalmanA Yeah, I'm always kind of surprised that JavaScript lets you change the behavior of `toString` and `valueOf` and properties of `window`, but doesn't have any concept of operator overloading.

Comment: @JacobKrall, ^^ not yet.

Comment: This is a lot more lines compared to JS

Comment: @carkod: How so? `class AlwaysEqual` has five lines of code (two of them unnecessary); `const a = {` on the accepted JavaScript answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/48270314/3140) is three lines of code. Everything else is testing to prove that it works.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what is `a`. We could create a class so it's instance would behave like shown above. What we have to do is to overload operators '==' and '!='.

```
    class StrangeInt
    {
        public static bool operator ==(StrangeInt obj1, int obj2)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public static bool operator !=(StrangeInt obj1, int obj2)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StrangeInt a = new StrangeInt();
        if(a==1 && a==2 && a==3)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hurraa");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

C# with Property

```
static int a = 1;
static int index
{
    get
    {                
        return (a++);
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (index == 1 && index == 2 && index == 3)
        Console.WriteLine("Hurraa");
}
```