# What will be the value of a every thing is allowed?

Tags: javascript

I want to run this if statement .

Help me to get the value of a.

```js
var a =undefined ;

if(a=1 && a=2 && a=3)
{
console.log("Hello")}

else
 {console.log("Error")
}
```

Comment: I can't understand what's your question. Can you clarify?

Comment: i want to run this if statement

Comment: what do i need to do to run this if statement, you can do any thing with upper part of the code (var a) but not allowed to change the if statement '

Comment: You want to check if `a` is equal to 3 different values at once? (just a heads up, its not..)

Comment: yes i want to check this

Answer (score -1):

The issue is with this line `if(a=1 && a=2 && a=3)`.Here the value is getting set to a instead of checking the condition

```js
var a = undefined;

if (a === 1 && a === 2 && a === 3) {
  console.log("Hello")
} else {
  console.log("Error")
}
```

> i want to run this if statement

a cannot be 1,2,3 at same time unless you are looking for [**something**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48270127/can-a-1-a-2-a-3-ever-evaluate-to-true) like this.Otherwise you can use or operator `||` instead of `&&`

Comment: i don't want to change the if statement, every thing is allowed but i can't change the if statement

Comment: @brk [Yes you can](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f@/LLFIIdHWkCszTUEj0dZIU6GaizM5P684PydVLyc/XSNRk6v2/38A), just the operator precedence is wrong.