# destructuring all exports in require statement to local variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I have a js file exporting a bunch of functions like so.

```
module.exports = {
  setScene : setScene,
  talk1: talk1,
  talk2: talk2,
  talk3: talk3,
  talk4: talk4,
  talk5: talk5,
  talk6: talk6,
  talk7: talk7,
  talk8: talk8,
  talk9: talk9,
  talk10: talk10,
  talk11: talk11,
  talk12: talk12,
  talk13: talk13,
  talk14: talk14,
  talk15: talk15,
  talk16: talk16,
  talk17: talk17,
  talk18: talk18,
  talk19: talk19,
  talk20: talk20,
  talk21: talk21,
  touchnose: touchnose,
  touchchin: touchchin,
  friendos: friendos,
  covermouth: covermouth,
  openmouth: openmouth,
  pointeye: pointeye,
  gameover: gameover,
  wait: wait
};
```

in my app.js file when I require the file, Is there a way I can destructure all of the values into local variables?

```
const { setScene, ...wait} = require('./components/play');
```

I'd like to be able to call the functions in my app.js without typing in every single value in the require statement.

Comment: Instead of `talk21: talk21,` just do `talk21,`

Comment: @JonasW. I don't think that's what OP asked for.

Comment: And no actually not. I think its impossible cause that could cause untrackable bugs

Comment: Did you know this `const { setScene, ...wait}` creates two variables?

Comment: yeah, this would put rest in one object

Comment: looking for a shorthand or something clever

Comment: It is unclear what you are actually asking for here.

Comment: @MattWay i've added some more information if you are confused

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is something clever, *please* don't do it though. It is not a default *for a good reason* - lexical scoping (being able to trace every identifier) is really important and useful. Doing this will not only slow down your code and only work when not in strict mode - it will also be confusing.

```
with(require('./components/play')) {
  // all exports are available here
}
```

Comment: Nice one :) `with` can always surprise one...

Comment: @JonasW. thanks, this is actually explicitly the purpose of `with` - to introduce dynamic scoping and why it is banned in strict mode. Most people think strict mode is for "nicer code" but it's actually for lexically scoped code so we could do https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/37199.pdf . Except for a few exceptions (which strict mode seals) JavaScript is lexically typed (so identifiers don't just 'appear' with values, except `this`).

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48270127/can-a-1-a-2-a-3-ever-evaluate-to-true/48270313#48270313 is also somehow related :)