# JS Class property validation function which returns boolean?

Tags: javascript, es6-class

I have an es6 model that I want to do some basic validation on before it is posted to an endpoint.  I wrote a simple isValid() method on the class which I want to return true or false, not truthy, falsey. Since && will return last check which was truthy, I shortcut the function by appending *&& true* to the end of my validation check.

```
export default class foo {
  constructor (data = {}) {
    this._id = data.id
    this._name = data.name
  }
  isValid () {
    return this._id && this._name && true
  }
}
```

What I want to know is: Is this an appropriate way to return a true value in this context?  Is there a better way to do this sort of validation in JS? I realize there are [other ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48270127/can-a-1-a-2-a-3-ever-evaluate-to-true) to return a boolean doing 'if' statements, but I wanted this to be fairly concise and thought this might be a valid shortcut...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write it like

```
  isValid () {
    return this._id && this._name && true
  }
```

it will return `true` for a `truthy` value but will not return `false` for a `falsy` value.

In order to return true or false, you can use the `Boolean` constructor function like

```
isValid () {
    return Boolean(this._id && this._name)
  }
```

or else you can make use of ternary operator

```
isValid () {
    return this._id && this._name? true : false
  }
```

**Demo snippet:**

```js
class foo {
  constructor (data = {}) {
    this._id = data.id
    this._name = data.name
  }
  isValid () {
    return Boolean(this._id && this._name)
  }
}

let foo1 = new foo({ id: 1, name: 'abc'});
let foo2 = new foo({ id: 2 });

console.log(foo1.isValid(), foo2.isValid());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can shorthand `!!` to cast into `boolean`.

```
return !!(this._id && this._name)
```