# Higher order function returns pure function

Tags: javascript, higher-order-functions, pure-function

Here's an example of an higher order function called functionA that has customValue as input and returns a function that gets an input and uses the custom value to elaborate a result:

```
let functionA = (customValue) => {
  let value = customValue || 1;
  return input => input * value;
};
```

Here's some results:

```
functionA()(4)             
// => returns 4

functionA(2)(4)
// => returns 8

functionA(3)(4)
// => returns 12

functionA(4)(4)
// => returns 16
```

Can the function returned by functionA be considered pure?

**UPDATE**: the examples above are only using numeric input. As described by @CRice, the returned function can be considered pure only when customValue is constant and doesn't have internal state (like classes).

Comment: There is healthy, meaningful discussion in the community about what "pure" means for functions. One (over?-)simplified definition is "no side effects"--no impact on variables/state outside the function scope that would make the function have different effects with the same input. Your functionA definitely meets that criterion. I say yes.

Comment: If you only consider reasonable input, i.e. `number` (or BigInt, now) – see CRice’s answer – then yes, it’s pure.

Comment: Some kindly folks upvoted my comment, but it's clear I misinterpreted the question. You did not ask "Is functionA pure?", but rather "Is the function returned by functionA always pure, by virtue of functionA?" As someone else answers below, I think the answer to this second question is "no".

Comment: Puzzles in JS are hard to solve with [many kinds of overloading available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48270127/can-a-1-a-2-a-3-ever-evaluate-to-true). (same for C++)

Comment: For OP: Don't edit the answer into the question. If you want to answer post an answer.

Comment: @pnknrg Not only the returned function is pure, but also the whole `functionA` should be considered pure

Comment: @AndyTaton What other definitions are there? Especially, are there any where it would be considered impure?

Comment: The question was edited since my comment. I don't think my caveat applies any more.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Using [this definition of Pure Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function):

> In computer programming, a pure function is a function that has the
>   following properties:
>
> 1. Its return value is the same for the same arguments (no variation with
>      local static variables, non-local variables, mutable reference
>      arguments or input streams from I/O devices).
> 2. Its evaluation has no
>      side effects (no mutation of local static variables, non-local
>      variables, mutable reference arguments or I/O streams).

Then, **no**, `functionA` will not always return a pure function.

Here is a way to use `functionA` so that it does not return a pure function:

```js
let functionA = (customValue) => {
  let value = customValue || 1;
  return input => input * value;
};

class Mutater {
  constructor() {
    this.i = 0;
  }
  valueOf() {
    return this.i++;
  }
}

const nonPureFunction = functionA(new Mutater());

// Produces different results for same input, eg: not pure.
console.log(nonPureFunction(10));
console.log(nonPureFunction(10));
```

As you can see, the returned function, when given the same input (`10`), produces a different result. This violates the first condition from the above definition (and using the same trick you could also violate the second).

Comment: so we can say that as long as customValue doesn't have internal state then the function returned by functionA is pure. Correct?

Comment: I would say yes, as long as `customValue` is constant. But you can also pass `mutator` as the argument to the returned function for the same kind of shenanigans. But would that still count as the "same input"? I don't know.

Comment: @pnknrg Would reading from e.g. a stream be considered "internal state"? I think one could just stick with the Wikipedia definition to find that `functionA` is pure if `customValue` is pure.

Comment: As long as you have mutable data types like Object in JS you will not have pure functions. JS is just a toy language trying to implement functional programming paradigm. With primitive data types like String this might not be the case though.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the function that is returned, can be considered pure. The reason that it is considered pure, is because the function will always return the same output given the exact same input.

Answer (score 0):

Your returned functions can be considered as pure function. In your example, you have effectively 4 different pure functions.

```
const pureFunc1 = functionA();
pureFunc1(4)   // => returns 4
pureFunc1(4)   // => returns 4

const pureFunc2 = functionA(2);
pureFunc2(4)   // => returns 8
pureFunc2(4)   // => returns 8

// ...
```