# Javascript test value is unchanged

Tags: javascript

At some point of my code I need to know that value is changed or not.

Something like this:

```
let a = {x:func1()};
let old_x = a.x;
func2(a);

if(x === old_x)
    console.log(`x wasn't changed`);
else
    console.log(`x is changed`);
```

And this code worked for some time but I encountered 'NaN'
And for NaN specs says NaN !== NaN will give 'true'... well this was quite a surprise to me, and now I wonder:

- Is there a uniform way in JavaScript to compare two values are the same?
- Is 'NaN' the only one special case in JavaScript and the following condition is a safe way to compare two values for equality?

  ```
  x === old_x || isNaN(old_x) && isNaN(x)
  ```

**Notice:**
For my case 'same' means

```
1 === 1 => true
null === null => true
undefined === null => false
undefined === undefined => true
NaN === NaN => true
'0' === 0 => false
Infinity === Infinity => true
...etc
```

Objects, arrays, functions and other 'reference types' are compared by reference:
i.e

```
let a = b = {}
a === b => true
but
a === {} => false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NaN` is indeed a special case. It's a special 'unique value' on that respect.

---

EDIT : I removed the part about objects, since you are aware of object reference comparisons.

---

> The following condition is a safe way to compare two values for equality :
>
> `old_x === x || isNaN(old_X) && isNaN(x)`

Not at all !

This can return `true` for instance if `old_x` and `x` are different strings not comparable to numbers.

Example, `isNaN("a")` and `isNaN("b")` will both return `true`!

You can use something similar, but you will have to test for the type of old_x and x to be "number" as well :

```
`old_x === x || typeof(old_x) === 'number' && typeof(x) === 'number' && isNaN(old_x) && isNaN(x)`
```

is ok for values.

Answer (score 2):

> Is 'NaN' the only one special case in Javascript and the following condition is a safe to compare two values for equallity?

Yes, exactly. For comparing the values `NaN` is the only exception, for comparing two variables / properties, such as:

```
 a === a
```

it [can be fun](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48270127/can-a-1-a-2-a-3-ever-evaluate-to-true/48270313#48270313)

Comment: the linked answer is related to something like `a == 1 && a == 2` and is specifically talking about the double equals (which can trigger potential coercion method executions and thus side effects). It doesn't show that `a === a` can cause any issue in this case.

Comment: @pac0 `with({ get a() { return ~~(Math.random() * 100); } }) { console.log(a === a); }`