# JavaScript template literals and implicit coercion

Tags: javascript, coercion, template-literals

What value should be assigned to `"x"` in order to meet the following condition:

```
// let x = ?; 

console.log(`${x}` != '' + x) // true
console.log(`${x}` !== '' + x) // true
```

Comment: I don't really think that the first case is possible.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Before the community can help you, we need to know what you have tried and why it didn't help - please edit the question to provide your thought process so far. Thanks.

Comment: write some more information about your question

Comment: Both the first and second case are tautological.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this can work, but it is tricky, the method `toString()` of the `x` object changes his internal state on every call and returns it. This happens because of the [implicit coercion](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/you-dont-know/9781491905159/ch04.html) that takes effect when trying to cast `x` to a string (it will use the `toString()` method of the object if found).

```js
let x = {
  counter: 1,
  toString: () => x.counter++
}

console.log('' + x);
console.log(`${x}`);

console.log(`${x}` != '' + x) // true
console.log(`${x}` !== '' + x) // true
```

Comment: Thank you @Shidersz this answer certainly meets the condition. Could you please explain whats happening or point to a resource where I can read about it. Also do you know other cases when this condition is met?

Comment: while this certainly "works", it has absolutely zero practical value.  What is the point of trying to compare if `x` isn't the same as itself, if you are so desperate to prove it that you go to the point of not even caring what the value of `x` even is?

Comment: @ebv Sure, you can found a lot of explanations here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48270127/can-a-1-a-2-a-3-ever-evaluate-to-true. But you need to read about [Javascript coercion](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/js-type-coercion-explained-27ba3d9a2839) too.

Comment: @Claies I agree with you, this sound more like an interview question.