# How to make the situation true JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript

I don't know what is the missing code here it's giving me a headache because of the conditional statement.

Add the missing codes so that the condition below will evaluate to TRUE and print “it works!” in the console.

```
if (num == 100 && num== 200 && num==300) {
    document.write('it works!');
} else {
    document.write('it doesnt');
}
```

Comment: A number cannot be `100`, `200`, ***and*** `300` at once.

Comment: Expect many, many more headaches :)

Comment: THIS IS YOUR ASSIGNMENT LMAO! anyway, should the codes be added before the conditional statement?

Comment: @JackBashford : HMR just proved you wrong :) (see below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_()), because with [logical AND `&&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND_()) the condition is never `true`, if you take the same value of `num`.

```
if (num == 100 || num== 200 || num == 300) {
```

But in Javascript everything is possible, like: [Can (a== 1 && a ==2 && a==3) ever evaluate to true?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48270127/1447675)

Answer (score 2):

If that's the real question you can do it using valueOf:

```js
    var Num = function() {
      this.values = [100, 200, 300];
      this.index = -1;
    };
    Num.prototype.valueOf = function() {
      this.index++;
      return this.values[this.index];
    };
    var num = new Num();
    if (num == 100 && num == 200 && num == 300) {
      console.log('it works!');
    } else {
      console.log('it doesnt');
    }
```

It may look like num is 100, 200 and 300 at once but the if statement has 3 expressions: `num == 100` then `num == 200` and then `num == 300`. Each time you compare num to a number with type coercion (using `==` instead of `===`) the `valueOf` will be invoked, that changes inner state of the num object instance so next time you compare it'll produce a different value.

I would not use type coercion comparing `==` and instead use `===`, when you use a linter it will usually complain when using `==` as it can cause some unexpected behavior and makes your code less predictable.

Comment: Wow, so `num` _can_ be 100, 200 and 300 at once! Twisted but impressive solution, have an upvote

Comment: @JeremyThille Nina actually added a link to similar "solution". valueOf and toString are used in type coercion.

Comment: You have disproved common sense. Congratulations.

Comment: Ah right, I didn't notice. This is messed up

Answer (score 0):

It will not satisfy the condition at a time and print "it doesn't".
So the solution would be like this.
`if(num==100 || num==200 || num==300)`

Comment: Yes but why? And what is the solution?

Comment: num has a value, and you are using AND operator for three different values, which will never satisfy.

Comment: That's the why, and what is the solution? You have to make a complete answer, not just say "The code doesn't work"

Comment: Yes I explained, and sometime you should think too.
So the solution would be use OR operator
if(num==100 || num==200 || num==300)

Comment: I have newly started to answer. Thanks for your guide.