# JavaScript: Property descriptors are ignored when passed to a function

Tags: javascript, arguments, descriptor, function-call, propertydescriptor

I want to pass getters/setters to a function but can't. Is it even possible to do (or emulate) such thing in JS?

I tried just calling a function with getters/setters but it (pretty obviously) doesn't work, I tried "apply" and "call" and it still (somehow) doesn't work.

```
function foo(x, y) {
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    console.log(x, y);
}

var args = [];

Object.defineProperties(args, {
  "0": {
    "set": function() { },
    "get": Math.random
  },

  "1": {
    "set": function() { },
    "get": function() { return new Date().getMilliseconds(); }
  }
});

foo.apply(this, args);
```

Expected 5 different results, got 5 the same instead.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding, but it seems to me that this program will generate random values for `x` and `y` when you pass in `args` to `foo` via the `apply` method - but that once inside `foo`, those arguments are fixed, and `foo` simply prints out those fixed values 5 times. It would be more interesting to do `foo.apply(null, args)` several times in a row (here the loop inside `foo` is irrelevant), then I guess you'd get different results each time.

Comment: btw, in ES6 it's more idiomatic to call `foo(...args)` rather than using `apply`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `.apply` converts your "array" into an `arguments` object, so your accessors will only be evaluated once.

You can get your example working by directly passing the array to the function:

```js
function foo(arr) {
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    console.log(arr[0], arr[1]);
}

var args = [];
Object.defineProperties(args, {
  "0": {
    "set": function() { },
    "get": Math.random
  },

  "1": {
    "set": function() { },
    "get": function() { return new Date().getMilliseconds(); }
  }
});

foo(args);
```

Comment: yes, that's more or less what I was just trying to say in my comment. I hadn't experimented with the code yet to be confident enough to turn it into an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. The `args` array is converted to a list of the individual values in `apply`, then the values themselves are passed as arguments.

A function parameter never will exhibit a getter functionality. There are [some horrible hacks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48270313/1048572) to make identifiers in a certain scope act as getters/setters, but you should never do that and you'd need to do that inside the function anyway.

Your best bet is to expect functions for the `x` and `y` parameters, and explicitly call them inside `foo`.