# What's the difference between: `a == b == c` and `a == b && a ==c`?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, boolean-expression

Hi I am trying to check if three values in a 2d array are the same.

I wanted to do this using the following statement:`board[0][i] == board[1][i] == board[2][i]`.

Unfortunately this gave me *false* as an answer, but the following statement result in true: `board[0][i] == board[1][i] && board[0][i] == board[2][i]`

I can't figure out why, any ideas?

Comment: If you want check for sameness, use the `===` operator. Or: use it always in javascript.

Answer (score 4):

Python supports that notation, but not javascript. So this evaluates the first comparison first and then compares the `true` result to the board[2][i] element, which is false.

I.e. this is the same as `(a == b) == c`, which has no clear relationship to equality of the given values. Consider these three values that are clearly different:

```js
a = 'x'
b = 'y'
c = false
console.log(a == b == c)
```

Also, note that `==` and `!=` are [evil and should never be used](https://stackoverflow.com/a/359509/2144408). Use `===` and `!==` instead.

Comment: board[2][i] could be truthy. Also this is a dupe

Comment: @mplungjan in the general case yes, but he states that the separate comparison yields true, so we can conclude that is not the case here.

Comment: Ahh I see, thanks for the insight! So a fuction like this should solve the problem? `function tripleequal(a, b, c){
  return (a == b && b == c && a == c);
}`

Comment: Can you think of an example where `a == b && b == c` but `a != c`?

Comment: I think that triple-equality is a more sensible default to use in that function.

Comment: @Rafalon that's not possible, surely?

Comment: @TamaMcGlinn [Nothing is impossible in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48270127/can-a-1-a-2-a-3-ever-evaluate-to-true). ;)

Comment: @TamaMcGlinn as Ivar pointed out, it is indeed possible, but highly unlikely in production code (unless one specifically wants to ruin his company). My comment was there to show that the last `&& a == c` was likely not needed