# Equality of ES6 Template Literal VS concatenated string

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
let x = ‽; // "‽" Could be any type(String, Array, Object, ...) The goal is to make the statement true 

`${x}` !=  '' + x // true

`${x}` !== '' + x // true
```

What should we assign to X to make the statements true?

I'm thinking it's not possible to make it true, but is there any exception?

Comment: `‽` is not a string.

Comment: @SebastianSimon I'm thinking the same :)

Comment: @NinaScholz Would you please explain? I tried a different type of value other than String but it always goes false since at the end it turns to String. `x = []; '' + x === ''`

Comment: please add the character as string to the question. actually it looks like a variable.

Comment: @PooriaHan It’s not about types; you should just clarify that you use `‽` as a placeholder.

Comment: Sure, I'm editing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a value that serializes to a different value every time it's converted to a string.

```js
const x = {
  [Symbol.toPrimitive]: (y => () => y++)(0),
};

console.log(`${x}` !== '' + x);
```

Comment: Maybe a bit easier to understand for the OP: `x = { toString: () => String(Math.random()) }` - But of course unlike your solution, this one has a super-miniscule chance (1 in 9 quadrillions) of returning the same value twice - on the other hand, your solution has a 100% chance of returning the same value twice after 9 quadrillion iterations ^^ so it doesn't matter

Comment: Reminds me of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48270127/1048572) trick question :-)

Comment: @CherryDT: Yeah, I had `Math.random` first :D

Answer (score 4):

Felix's answer covers one absolutely valid approach, but I'll add another one here that doesn't require incrementing or random values.

```
`${x}`
```

converts `x` to a string using [`ToString`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-tostring), which in the case of `x` being an object, does `ToPrimitive(argument, string)`.

```
'' + x
```

on the other hand uses [`ApplyStringOrNumericBinaryOperator`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-applystringornumericbinaryoperator), which does `ToPrimitive(rval)`.

You can take advantage of that difference in the 2nd parameter of the function. For example:

```
x = {
  [Symbol.toPrimitive](hint) {
    if (hint === "string") {
      return 'a';
    } else {
      return 'b';
    }
  },
};
```

and now in this case

```
`${x}` === 'a' // true
'' + x === 'b' // true
```

You can also see this without Symbol by directly using `toString` and `valueOf`:

```
x = { 
  toString(){ return 'a'; }, 
  valueOf(){ return 'b'; },
};
```

which produces the same thing as the last example, because `valueOf` is the default unless a string value is explicitly hinted, as in the case for `${x}`.

Comment: I was actually wondering whether one of those two operations prefers "the other" conversion method first but didn't bother to look. Nice one.

Comment: @FelixKling It's definitely not one I'd know either except that it came up as a bug for Babel's template string compilation way back, since it originally output a chain of `+` operations.