# Is it possible a === 1 && a === 2 & a === 3 return true in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, compare

Actually, this question is an extension of [Can (a== 1 && a ==2 && a==3) ever evaluate to true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48270127/can-a-1-a-2-a-3-ever-evaluate-to-true) .

As we may know, The secret of [loose equality operator (==)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#loose_equality_using) will try to convert both values to a common type. As a result, some functions will be invoked.

> `ToPrimitive(A)` attempts to convert its object argument to a primitive
> value, by invoking varying sequences of `A.toString` and `A.valueOf`
> methods on A.

So the following code will work as expected.

```js
const a = {
  i: 1,
  toString: function () {
    return a.i++;
  }
}

if(a == 1 && a == 2 && a == 3) {
  console.log('Hello World!');
}
```

However, The problem in the case of `strict equality (===)`. Methods such as `.valueOf`, `.toString`, or `Symbol.toPrimitive` won’t be called by JavaScript Engine.

How can I resolve it? Any help would be appreciated.

```js
const a = {
  i: 1,
  toString: function () {
    return a.i++;
  }
}

if(a === 1 && a === 2 && a === 3) {
  console.log('Never catch!');
}
```

Comment: Please read all the answer of the question you linked. Many will work with `===` as well.

Comment: @Bergi I did. But none of them pointed out it works with `strict equality (===)`. Besides, I did google, searched on SO no existing topics like this. So IMO, it's worth having a specific topic like this :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some of the methods on the other page work with strict equality, just avoid the ones that utilize `toString` or `valueOf`.

```js
let num = 1;
Object.defineProperty(window, 'a', { get() { return num++ } });
// or use `with` and an object with a getter instead of putting it on the window

if(a === 1 && a === 2 && a === 3) {
  console.log('Never catch!');
}
```

This works because `a` is not a normal variable - it's a getter on the window, so when the identifier `a` is referenced, the getter runs and can return any value. Here, it'll return an incremented integer.

Other methods in the linked question will work with strict equality, if you wish to permit them:

- [Using invisible characters in the variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48274520)
- [Using a worker with a race condition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48295891)
- [Using a fake `if` as a function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48362981)
- [Using large integer imprecision](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48298565)

Comment: Could you pls explain more how it works? Thanks.

Comment: It’s good to note that you can’t return an object and expect it to === with any number because it checks the type under the hood.