# How to check whether the state has no empty value In React app,

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, mern

This is the state of the Application.
Validate function should return true if there are non zero, non empty and non empty array inside the state...

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
    priceType: 0,
    recurrenceType: 0,
    start_date: '',
    end_date: '',
    minCapacity: 0,
    maxCapacity: 0,
    price: 0,
    min: 0,
    max: 0,
    days: []
});
```

I'm trying in this way but not giving correct result,

```
const validate=Object.values(state).every((item)=>(item===0 && item==='' && item===[]))
```

Any suggestion....

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Standard equality (`==` or `===`) [doesn't work with objects (and arrays)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript):

```js
console.log([] === []) // false
console.log({} === {}) // false
```

In addition, you can't use `&&` because logically and usually `item` can't be `0` , an empty string, and an empty array at the same time ([there are tricks to do so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48270127/can-a-1-a-2-a-3-ever-evaluate-to-true), but they are not fitting for this question).

To make sure that you don't have empty values use `Array.some()` to check if it least one is empty, and negate the results. To make sure that all are empty use `Array.every()`.

To check if an array is empty, check that it's `length` is not `0` (this also works with strings). So you can just check the length, and if that returns undefined, check if it's `0`:

```js
const state = {
  priceType: 0,
  recurrenceType: 0,
  start_date: '',
  end_date: '',
  minCapacity: 0,
  maxCapacity: 0,
  price: 0,
  min: 0,
  max: 0,
  days: []
};

const validate = !Object.values(state)
  .some(item => item === 0 || item.length === 0);
  
console.log(validate);
```