# How to fix days.map is not a function error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mern

My map function is,

```
 days.map((val)=>val)
```

when I consoling days prop it gives me,

```
  [Array(7)]
  0: (7) ['', '', '', 'Wednesday', '', '', 'Saturday']
  length: 1
```

Hence days is an array,so why this error occures?

Below is the image of console.log()
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRQrr.png

This is the component in which I am using the days Prop..

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Table from '@mui/material/Table';
import TableBody from '@mui/material/TableBody';
import TableCell from '@mui/material/TableCell';
import TableContainer from '@mui/material/TableContainer';
import TableHead from '@mui/material/TableHead';
import TableRow from '@mui/material/TableRow';
import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper';
import {
    Card,
    CardMedia,
    CardActions,
    Icon,
    Grid,
    Radio,
    Button,
    RadioGroup,
    FormControlLabel,
    Select as MuiSelect,
    MenuItem,
    FormControl,
    InputLabel,
    IconButton,
    CircularProgress,
    Divider,
    Snackbar, Alert, Typography
} from '@mui/material';

function SpecialPriceTable({
    tableData,
    days
}) {
    return (

        <TableContainer component={Paper}>
            <Table sx={{ minWidth: 650 }} size="small" aria-label="a dense table">
                <TableHead>
                    <TableRow>
                        <TableCell align="right">Start Date</TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="right">End Date</TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="right">Recurrence</TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="right">Price Type</TableCell>
                        <TableCell sx={{ pr: 3 }} align="right">Pice</TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                </TableHead>
                <TableBody>
                    {tableData.map((data, index) => (
                        <TableRow
                            key={index}
                            sx={{ '&:last-child td, &:last-child th': { border: 0 } }}
                        >
                            <TableCell align="right">
                                {data.start_date}
                            </TableCell>

                            <TableCell align="right">
                                {data.end_date}
                            </TableCell>

                            {/* <TableCell align="right">
                                {data.recurrenceType === 1 ? 'All day' : data.recurrenceType === 2 ? 'Weekend(Every Saturday and Sunday)' :
                                    data.recurrenceType === 3 ? days.map((item) => item.join(' ')) : ''}
                            </TableCell> */}

                            {console.log(days[0].map(val=>val))}

                            <TableCell align="right">
                                {data.priceType === 0 ? 'Whole' : data.priceType === 1 ? 'Per Person' : data.priceType === 2 ? 'Per Hours' : ''}
                            </TableCell>

                            <TableCell sx={{ pr: 3 }} align="right">
                                {data.price}
                            </TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                    ))}
                </TableBody>
            </Table>
        </TableContainer>

    )
}
```

export default SpecialPriceTable

Thanks,any suggestion accepted..

Comment: how `days` array looks like?

Comment: sometimes, `console.log` can display a value that's not necessarily the value at the time of logging the variable.

Comment: Already given on that image  @DecPK

Comment: can you give us a code snippet?

Comment: It looks like your days array may be an array with only a single value, which itself is an array. 

Could you try doing `days[0].map(val => val)`?

Comment: this though doesnt answer the `days.map is not a function` error. it should run even for this one element. so there is sth else inside the code.

Comment: I have tried this days[0].map(val => val),Bu not working @mjwils

Comment: are you sure `days` is always an array throughout your state? this is the only thing i can think of.

Comment: Are you using typeScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot know how your `days` property is initialized based on the code snippet.
Maybe somewhere is it initialized as an object not as an array and then somehow it is converted to array.

Please check the initialization of your `days` property and change that.
You can also add this check `Array.isArray(days)`

```
<TableCell align="right">
 {data.recurrenceType === 1 ? 'All day' : data.recurrenceType === 2 ? 'Weekend(Every Saturday and Sunday)' :
 data.recurrenceType === 3 ? (Array.isArray(days) ? days.map((item) => item.join(' ')) : '-') : ''}
                            </TableCell>
```

Comment: plz check this and suggest any solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73947682/how-to-check-whether-the-state-has-no-empty-value-in-react-app/73947803#73947803

Comment: answer given there is ok. what is the problem?

Comment: I want to validate the state,wheather the objects having any null value or not.So that I perform submit action.

Comment: yes i saw that, but the answer is OK. it does what you need.

Comment: I have already tried that same but not working.

Comment: Is there any other way to validate.

Comment: so `validate` function should return `true` if all are OK? non zero, non empty and non empty array?

Comment: yes,validate function will return true if all are ok

Comment: so i guess you need this. `const validate=Object.values(state).every((item)=>(item!==0 && item!=='' && JSON.stringify(item)!=='[]'))` if yes, let me know so i can post my answer!

Comment: https://prnt.sc/iosaCLE1yMqZ , https://prnt.sc/KBtNYZckCrmh .Check these Images.Not working,I mean when there is no value inside the state and I click on save button and execute that function it goes inside else.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/i9nQmySwzJr3   ,   https://prnt.sc/A1MsPmNZJgSG

Comment: validate returns true if all have data. you have the opposite here. you have negation. remove `!`

Comment: Yes,but the thing is, some objects of the the state are dynamic so your solution returns false always till all the objects of the state are having their values.https://prnt.sc/cLeXZVuEW5TG ,https://prnt.sc/umM4bELm63nO .....look at these screenshots