# What does "value != value" mean in JS?

Tags: javascript

I was reading the [source code of `core-js`](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/blob/master/packages/core-js/internals/array-includes.js) and I saw the following:

```
if (value != value) return true;
```

What does it actually mean? When exactly `value` won't be equal to itself?

Comment: it looks like an old `NaN` check. please see duplicate above.

Comment: @NinaScholz This question isn't really a duplicate of that question. The questions are completely different and the answers just happen to be (somewhat) similar. CertainPerformance's answer shows that this could be something that isn't a NaN check.

Comment: The comment on the line above the quoted line explicitly says that it's a NaN check.

Comment: @MichaelM., for the other case this would be the duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48270127/1447675

Comment: @MichaelM. no, `value` will be exceptionally likely ***not*** be a getter property which changes on reads. It is exceptionally likely to be a *value*. Unless you have really, really, *really*, ***really*** strong evidence to suggest that the core-js library i̶s̶ ̶i̶n̶s̶a̶n̶e̶ will for some reason decide to define a getter property and check it by reading it twice. As opposed to getting a value and checking for `NaN`. In general, I've never *once* in my entire life seen any serious code use a getter property and check it against itself. I've *only* seen it as "haha, you can do this" example.

Comment: @MichaelM. also, given that the line of code ***that defines `value`*** is `value = O[index++];` it is literally impossible for `value` to be a getter property. It's always ***guaranteed*** to be a plain value. The comment right above `value !== value` also reads "NaN check". Of course, if you have evidence that it's not checking for `NaN`, feel free to share.

Comment: This is used by lodash as part of `isEqual` logic (well it actually uses `!==` but I'm guessing there isn't a difference in usage). The following definitely made my head spin a little when I read it: `return value !== value && other !== other` https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/.internal/baseIsEqual.js

Answer (score 4):

It could be if:

- `value` is NaN

```js
console.log(NaN != NaN);
```

- `value` is actually a getter on the global object, and it returns something different each time:

```js
let i = 0;
Object.defineProperty(window, 'value', { get: () => i++ });

console.log(value != value);
```