# Difference between Object.create(foo) and new Object(foo)?

Tags: javascript

Why is that this code:

```
var foo = {one: 1, two: 2};
var bar = new Object( foo );
bar.three = 3;
bar.one = 100; 
document.write(bar.one); //100 
document.write(foo.one); //100
```

results in bar.one & foo.one being both 100, while

```
var foo = {one: 1, two: 2};
var bar = Object.create( foo );
bar.three = 3;
bar.one = 100; 
document.write(bar.one); //100
document.write(foo.one); //1
```

only affects bar.one..

My first intuition is that since in the first piece of code we are assigning a foo reference to bar, then it means the change will also apply to foo, while on the second code, it probably 'inherits' from foo, and therefore the change on bar's 'subclass' attribute won;t apply to its 'superclass' (prototype)..

Can somebody please confirm that my assumption is at least on the right track? Would absolutely appreciate any answers. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The line:

```
var bar = new Object( foo );
```

In your first snippet, it doesn't do anything -you are right with your assumption-, it will simply return a reference to the same object passed to the `Object` constructor.

That's the behavior when you pass a *native object* to the `Object` constructor in a `new` expression ([`new Object(value)`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.2.2.1)), if you pass a [*host object*](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:7jGjZFWhwsgJ:www.jibbering.com/faq/#hostObject), the results are implementation dependent.

If you don't pass a value (or you explicitly pass the primitives `undefined` or `null`) a new object that inherits from `Object.prototype` will be created.

Otherwise, if you pass any of the remaining primitives (as a Number, String or a Boolean value), a *primitive wrapper object* will be created (basically "primitive-to-object" type conversion), for example.

```
var s = new String("foo"); // a string object wrapper
typeof s;     // "object"
s.valueOf();  // "foo"
```

<sup>See this question about primitives and objects: [How is a Javascript string not an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907613/how-is-a-javascript-string-not-an-object)</sup>

In your second snippet, the line:

```
var bar = Object.create( foo );
```

Creates a new object, that inherits from `foo`, and since it's a different object, when you assign the properties:

```
bar.three = 3;
bar.one = 100;
```

Those will be created physically on that separated *instance*, as you can see, the `bar.one` property **shadows** the value contained in `foo`.

The object referenced by `bar`, in fact will contain two **own properties** (`one` and `three`, but since it inherits from `foo`, the property named `two` is resolvable through the prototype chain, for example:

```
bar.hasOwnProperty('one'); // true, the property is "own"
bar.hasOwnProperty('two'); // false, the property is "inherited" from foo
bar.two; // 2, is accessible
```

Basically, the prototype chain of `bar` looks like this:

```
                                                      -----------------
                                           ========> | Object.prototype| ==> null
                                           |          -----------------
|-------------|     [[Prototype]]     |---------|
| one:   100  | ====================> |  one: 1 | (shadowed)
| three: 3    |                       |  two: 2 |
|-------------|                       |---------|

(== line denotes the prototype chain)
```

Comment: thanks for the response..so does it mean that my assumption is correct? that var bar = new Object(foo) is pretty much the same as var bar = foo therefore bar now stores the reference of foo? and also, what is a primitive wrapper?

Comment: @BennyTija: Yeah, that means your assumption is correct. A primitive wrapper is an object that wraps a primitive value, like Java's Integer class. There isn't much use for them, although if you're calling a lot of methods on a primitive it can help to wrap it for performance reasons.

Comment: @BennyTija, as @alpha123 says, your assumption is right, about primitive wrappers, Javascript has five primitive types, which are String, Number, Boolean, Null and Undefined, values of this types are *primitive*, they are not objects, basically primitive wrappers are objects that store a primitive internally, they are not so useful on the language because you can still access properties on primitive values, e.g. `"foo".charAt(0); // "f"`. They are actually a heritage from Java... See my answer on the question I [linked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907613/).

Answer (score 2):

`new Object` and `Object.create` do completely different things, despite their similar sounding names.

`new Object()`, with no argument, is equivalent to an empty object literal `{}`, which you should always use instead. With an argument, `new Object(obj)` simply returns the argument.

`Object.create(obj)` helps untangle JavaScript's messed up prototypal inheritance. Reading [this](http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html) article by Douglas Crockford will help with that. Basically, it creates a new object that inherits from `obj`. So if you have

```
var obj1 = {x: 1}, obj2 = Object.create(obj1);

obj1.x; // 1
obj2.x; // 1

obj2.x = 42;
obj1.x; // 1

obj1.x = 10;
obj2.x; // 10, since obj2 inherits from obj1, changing obj1's properties
        // changes obj2, but not the other way around.
```