# Can a function be considered similar to a class?

Tags: javascript, c++

If I have a function say:

```
var my_function = function()
  {
  }
```

If the function is not called, it is not taking up memory, it is just text sitting in memory.

However if you call it by say...

```
function_instance = new my_function();
```

It is instantiated is a sort of way, and the variables and methods it contains are loaded into memory.

Is this a way to represent a class/object model similar to C++?

Is my interpretation correct?

Comment: Could you ask more precisely?

Comment: Either your interpretation is incorrect, or your terminology is very... "unusual".

Comment: In what way do you think this would be similar to C++?

Comment: "and the variables and methods it contains are loaded into memory" how does that apply to a function? does a function have methods in javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*a way to represent a class/object model similar to C++*" would be through the use of prototypes.

As Kevin M pointed out, you can use the `this` keyword to create instance variables in a function, like so:

```
var my_function(foo)
{
  this.foo = foo;
  this.bar = function()
  {
    // bar-ing here
  }
}
```

The problem however, that whenever you instantiate `my_function()`, a new instance of the `my_function.bar` function is also created. Enter `prototype`s:

```
var barPrototype = { "bar" : function()
  {
    // bar-ing here
  }
};

var my_function(foo)
{
  this.foo = foo;
}
my_function.prototype = barPrototype;
```

So, to sum it all up, the `prototype` keyword can be used to create function-specific, inheritable properties that are analoguous to C++'s member functions. Member functions of C++ aren't instantiated for each instance of a class. Instead, the compiler adds a `this` pointer to the function's parameters; this pointer points to the instance that the member function is called on.

More JSey fun to be had here: http://javascript.infogami.com/Javascript_in_Ten_Minutes

Answer (score 3):

In javascript, the class concept does not exist. Everything is an object. When you use the new operator it copies the prototype of that function into a new object. In other words, you can emulate what class can do in c++, but it's not a class.

Comment: @Francis, right, he concept of "class" doesn't exist *yet* on the language, *constructor functions* are often called "classes" and although this may seem just a small terminology problem, it will be a real mess when the `class` syntax will be finally approved and standardized, probably for the next edition of ECMAScript, you won't know if somebody it talking about constructor functions or "real" ECMAScript classes... I don't agree with the *"Everything is an object."* part, the language has *primitive types*, and they are *not* objects, more info: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3907613#3907659

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript a new class is defined by creating a function. The function may contain other functions (methods), properties, etc.

When a function is called using the new operation the function becomes a constructor for that class. Inside the constructor the variable " this " is created and points to the object.

```
function Man(){
    this.name = 'John';
}

var person = new Man;
console.log(person.name);
```

Comment: It is designed to behave like a class. They are pretty much the same thing. This is object oriented JavaScript. A nice link to read more about polymorphism, sub classing, prototyping, inheritance, etc http://mckoss.com/jscript/object.htm

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, Javascript functions can act as objects so Javascript can be object oriented but object inheritance is prototypical and not like C++.  John Resig, the creator of jQuery, has done some work on emulating traditional classes and inheritance in javascript.  You could take a look at his blog for an interesting example:

http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/