# access data in json not getting the key

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```js
var data = [{
 "error": false,
 "date": "09-02-2016",
 "day": "5",
 "checkin": "20:29:11",
 "checkout": null,
 "break_timein": null,
 "break_timeout": null,
 "checkin_remarks": "test",
 "checkout_remarks": null,
 "break_time_remarks": null
}];



console.log(data[0].checkin)
console.log(data[0].break_timein)
console.log(data[0].break_timein.length > 0 || data[0].break_timein != null)
```

For `break_timein` when i console.log it, it returns null but when I get the length it returns `Cannot read property 'length' of null`

Why is this?

Comment: its because you can not get a length of null

Comment: @ÖzgürErsil how do you suggest to fix it to make it boolean? i want to put it inside `if(data[0].break_timein.length > 0 || data[0].break_timein != null)`

Comment: This feels like a completely self-explanatory problem when I see the error, so I think you might have to elaborate on what your mental understanding of your object is, and how it's not fitting your thinking. In regards to the comment above: You most likely want `etc != null &&`, instead of `||`. A null-check *before* checking something's value is pretty common, but you can't do it afterward, and you can't use an OR operator.

Comment: @Katana314 i understand that it only appears when there is not property `break_timein` but it is there its just `null`

Comment: @BrownmanRevival: `undefined` and `null` behave the same way wrt to property access: You cannot access a property on them. As already said, the error is pretty self-explanatory: *"Cannot read property 'length' of **null**"* . Lets simplify the problem: Type `null.length` and `undefined.length` in the console.

Comment: @FelixKling ok will try it thanks for explanation can you add solution this explanation to answer?

Comment: @FelixKling correct me if im wrong when using `!=` it will treat `"null"` and `null` same right? so if the value of `data[0].break_timein` is `"null"` it will still be true?even if it really has value.

Comment: What do you mean by "the same"? *"if the value of data[0].break_timein is "null" it will still be true"* `"null"` is a non-empty string, so it evaluates to `true` if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I understand that it only appears when there is not property `break_timein` but it is there its just `null`

You drew the wrong conclusion here. The error doesn't have anything to do with whether a property exists or not.

When a property doesn't exist and you are trying to access a property on it you are getting the following error:

```
var foo = {};
foo.bar.baz;
// Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'baz' of undefined
```

The "undefined" in this sentence doesn't refer to the *existence* of the property, it refers to the **value** `undefined`. In JavaScript, when accessing a property doesn't exist, accessing it will return the value `undefined`:

```
foo.bar
// undefined
```

There are other situations where `undefined` is created, e.g. when you define a variable without an initial value:

```
var abc;
abc;
// undefined
```

Knowing that we can test what happens when we directly access a property on `undefined`:

```
undefined.foo
//  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'foo' of undefined
```

This throws the same error as above, so it doesn't have anything to do with property access.

---

So now we have established that `undefined` cannot be used in a property access context.

`null` is another value that is just like that:

```
null.foo
// Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'foo' of null
```

What makes `null` and `undefined` different from other primitive values (string, number, boolean) that they show this behavior?

`null` and `undefined` are actually values of two unique *data types*: Null and Undefined.

Those data types **do not** have an **object wrapper**. Strings, Numbers and Boolean values can exist in two forms: as primitive values and as object value:

```
var primitive = "foo";
var object = new String("foo");
```

When you are accessing a property on a *primitive* value, e.g. `"foo".length`, JavaScript [automatically converts the primitive value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907613/how-is-a-javascript-string-not-an-object/3907659#3907659) to a [*temporary* object value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201138/why-cant-i-add-properties-to-a-string-object-in-javascript/5201148#5201148), similar to `new String("foo").length`.

But since there is no object equivalent for Null`and Undefined` (evident by the fact that there is no `Null` or `Undefined` function), this cannot be done, so an error is thrown.

Comment: what i mean when i said earlier is when the value of `data[0].break_timein` is the string null. in current condition `data[0].break_timein != null` this will evaluate to true even if the value is string `null`. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: The only values for which `x == null` is `true` is `null` and `undefined`. So yes, `x != null` will be `true` for *any* value, except `null`and `undefined`.

Comment: thank you for explanation im really confused with these things :) happy coding mate

Answer (score 0):

Here, `null` doesn't have any properties eg- length that's why it's throwing an error saying `"Cannot read property 'length' of null"`. You should write the statement like this:

```
console.log(data[0].break_timein != null || data[0].break_timein.length > 0);
```

Comment: This is probably minor semantics not important to the issue, but I don't think of `null` as an object. It is in Ruby, but not JavaScript - you can check the `length` property of `{}`, which is an object, but since that property isn't on the object, it will be `undefined`. On the other hand, checking any property of `null` will actually cause an error.