# Check NULL in Jquery Append

Tags: php, jquery

Good day. I'm trying to check a value from `jquery append`. Here is My Jquery

```
 success: function(resultData){
            $.each(resultData, function(key, val) { 
                no ++;
                    $("#result").append('<tr>  <td>' + no + '</td> <td> ' + val.FullName + 
                    '</td> <td> ' +val.attendancedate+ '  </td>'+
                    '<td>' + val.InTime + '</td>'+ 
                    '<td>' + val.OutTime + '</td>'+
                    '<td>' + val.total + '</td>' +
                    <?php if(($kode_tipe == "SPV_HO") or ($Nip == "1105321")){ ?> 
                    '<td> <a href="<?=base_url();?><?=$controller;?>/edit_jam/'+ val.nip+'/'+val.attendancedate+'/' +kode+'"> Edit </a> </td>' +
                     <?php } ?>
                    '</tr>');
            });
          }
```

so . I want to check in this part

```
'<td>' + val.InTime + '</td>'+ 
'<td>' + val.OutTime + '</td>'+
```

so the logic is below :

```
if($InTime == NULL)
{
  echo "No Time";
}else{
  echo $InTime;
}
```

I really don't know how to do it with jquery. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the resultData

```
[{"Nip":"1602744","FullName":"RAHMAT ","KodeDetailDinas":1,"KodeDinasHeader":"DN0000001","nip":"1602744"
,"attendancedate":"2016-09-14","dayname":"Wednesday","InTime":null,"OutTime":null,"week":38,"total":null
},{"Nip":"1602744","FullName":"RAHMAT ","KodeDetailDinas":1,"KodeDinasHeader":"DN0000001","nip":"1602744"
,"attendancedate":"2016-09-15","dayname":"Thursday","InTime":null,"OutTime":null,"week":38,"total":null
},{"Nip":"1602744","FullName":"RAHMAT ","KodeDetailDinas":1,"KodeDinasHeader":"DN0000001","nip":"1602744"
,"attendancedate":"2016-09-16","dayname":"Friday","InTime":null,"OutTime":null,"week":38,"total":null
},{"Nip":"1602744","FullName":"RAHMAT ","KodeDetailDinas":1,"KodeDinasHeader":"DN0000001","nip":"1602744"
,"attendancedate":"2016-09-17","dayname":"Saturday","InTime":null,"OutTime":null,"week":38,"total":null
},{"Nip":"1602744","FullName":"RAHMAT ","KodeDetailDinas":1,"KodeDinasHeader":"DN0000001","nip":"1602744"
,"attendancedate":"2016-09-18","dayname":"Sunday","InTime":null,"OutTime":null,"week":39,"total":null
},{"Nip":"1602744","FullName":"RAHMAT ","KodeDetailDinas":1,"KodeDinasHeader":"DN0000001","nip":"1602744"
,"attendancedate":"2016-09-19","dayname":"Monday","InTime":null,"OutTime":null,"week":39,"total":null
},{"Nip":"1602744","FullName":"RAHMAT ","KodeDetailDinas":1,"KodeDinasHeader":"DN0000001","nip":"1602744"
,"attendancedate":"2016-09-20","dayname":"Tuesday","InTime":null,"OutTime":null,"week":39,"total":null
},{"Nip":"1602744","FullName":"RAHMAT ","KodeDetailDinas":1,"KodeDinasHeader":"DN0000001","nip":"1602744"
,"attendancedate":"2016-09-21","dayname":"Wednesday","InTime":null,"OutTime":null,"week":39,"total":null
```

Comment: @guradio that for PHP right? i want write it in jquery

Comment: `val.InTime.length > 0 ? val.InTime : ""`

Comment: @guradio i got this error `TypeError: val.InTime is null`

Comment: can you include the `resultData`?

Comment: @guradio i have update my question.

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
success: function(resultData){
        $.each(resultData, function(key, val) { 
            no ++;
            var inTime = (!val.InTime) ? 'No Time' : val.InTime;

                $("#result").append('<tr>  <td>' + no + '</td> <td> ' + val.FullName + 
                '</td> <td> ' +val.attendancedate+ '  </td>'+
                '<td>' + inTime + '</td>'+ 
                '<td>' + val.OutTime + '</td>'+
                '<td>' + val.total + '</td>' +
                <?php if(($kode_tipe == "SPV_HO") or ($Nip == "1105321")){ ?> 
                '<td> <a href="<?=base_url();?><?=$controller;?>/edit_jam/'+ val.nip+'/'+val.attendancedate+'/' +kode+'"> Edit </a> </td>' +
                 <?php } ?>
                '</tr>');
        });
      }
```

Your code could use some refactoring.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var data = [{
  "Nip": "1602744",
  "FullName": "RAHMAT ",
  "KodeDetailDinas": 1,
  "KodeDinasHeader": "DN0000001",
  "nip": "1602744",
  "attendancedate": "2016-09-14",
  "dayname": "Wednesday",
  "InTime": null,
  "OutTime": null,
  "week": 38,
  "total": null
}, {
  "Nip": "1602744",
  "FullName": "RAHMAT ",
  "KodeDetailDinas": 1,
  "KodeDinasHeader": "DN0000001",
  "nip": "1602744",
  "attendancedate": "2016-09-15",
  "dayname": "Thursday",
  "InTime": null,
  "OutTime": null,
  "week": 38,
  "total": null
}, {
  "Nip": "1602744",
  "FullName": "RAHMAT ",
  "KodeDetailDinas": 1,
  "KodeDinasHeader": "DN0000001",
  "nip": "1602744",
  "attendancedate": "2016-09-16",
  "dayname": "Friday",
  "InTime": null,
  "OutTime": null,
  "week": 38,
  "total": null
}, {
  "Nip": "1602744",
  "FullName": "RAHMAT ",
  "KodeDetailDinas": 1,
  "KodeDinasHeader": "DN0000001",
  "nip": "1602744",
  "attendancedate": "2016-09-17",
  "dayname": "Saturday",
  "InTime": null,
  "OutTime": null,
  "week": 38,
  "total": null
}, {
  "Nip": "1602744",
  "FullName": "RAHMAT ",
  "KodeDetailDinas": 1,
  "KodeDinasHeader": "DN0000001",
  "nip": "1602744",
  "attendancedate": "2016-09-18",
  "dayname": "Sunday",
  "InTime": null,
  "OutTime": null,
  "week": 39,
  "total": null
}, {
  "Nip": "1602744",
  "FullName": "RAHMAT ",
  "KodeDetailDinas": 1,
  "KodeDinasHeader": "DN0000001",
  "nip": "1602744",
  "attendancedate": "2016-09-19",
  "dayname": "Monday",
  "InTime": null,
  "OutTime": null,
  "week": 39,
  "total": null
}, {
  "Nip": "1602744",
  "FullName": "RAHMAT ",
  "KodeDetailDinas": 1,
  "KodeDinasHeader": "DN0000001",
  "nip": "1602744",
  "attendancedate": "2016-09-20",
  "dayname": "Tuesday",
  "InTime": null,
  "OutTime": null,
  "week": 39,
  "total": null
}, {
  "Nip": "1602744",
  "FullName": "RAHMAT ",
  "KodeDetailDinas": 1,
  "KodeDinasHeader": "DN0000001",
  "nip": "1602744",
  "attendancedate": "2016-09-21",
  "dayname": "Wednesday",
  "InTime": null,
  "OutTime": null,
  "week": 39,
  "total": null
}]

$.each(data, function(key, val) {


val.InTime !=null ? console.log(val.InTime) : console.log("")





});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Use `!= null`
For further clarification visit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39293076/access-data-in-json-not-getting-the-key)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
if (val.InTime.length > 0){
  $("#result").text(InTime);
} else {
  $("#result").text("No Time");
}
```

Comment: how do i `echo` it?

Comment: You want check null in jquery and then echo in php ?

Answer (score 0):

From my view your rendering logic is quiet complex,instead of writing whole html rendering code try this :

```
$.each(resultdata, function(val,index){
   var tr = $('<tr>');
   tr.append($('<td>',{
       'text': "no"
   }));
   tr.append($('<td>',{
       'text': val.FullName
   }));
   tr.append($('<td>',{
       'text': val.attendancedate
   }));
   if(val.InTime === "NULL"){
      tr.append($('<td>',{
         'text': "No Time"
      }));
   }else {
       tr.append($('<td>',{
         'text': val.InTime
      }));
   }
   //Do the same for out time as well
   $("#result").append(tr);
});
```

Try this.